# python: Ошибка при вычислении и сложении

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Написал команду "Машина улучшить 1" (улучшение машины), но обрабатывается команда неправильно, мой код:

```
    elif message.text == 'машина улучшить 1' or message.text == 'Машина улучшить 1': # команда Машина улучшить (ИД)
        if os.path.isfile(f"C://tgplay/{message.chat.id}_avto1.py"):
            file = open(f'C://tgplay/{message.chat.id}_avto1.py', 'r')
            schet = int(file.read())
            file.close
            if schet == int('70'):
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ваша машина уже улучшена до максимум!')
                return
            file = open(f'c://tgplay/{message.chat.id}_money.py', 'r+')
            money = int(file.read())
            file.close
            if money < int(11000):
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'У вас недостаточно средств для улучшения!')
                return
            else:
                file = open(f'c://tgplay/{message.chat.id}_avto1.py', 'r+')
                lsid = file.read()
                num = int(lsid)
                file.seek(0)
                file.write(str(num+1))
                file.seek(0)
                file.close
                file = open(f'C://tgplay/{message.chat.id}_money.py', 'r+')
                filemoney = int(file.read())
                file.seek(0)
                file.write(str(filemoney-11000))
                file.seek(0)
                file.close
            # подсчет всего
                file = open(f'c://tgplay/{message.chat.id}_money.py', 'r')
                itogmoney = int(file.read())
                file.close
                file = open(f'c://tgplay/{message.chat.id}_avto1.py', 'r')
                itogmon = int(file.read())
                file.close
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'{message.from_user.first_name}, вы успешно улучшили свою машину!\n    Добавлено: +1 лошадиных сил.\n    Лошадиных сил теперь: ' + str(itogmon) + '!\n Ваш баланс: ' + str(itogmoney))
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'У вас нету машины!')
```

Когда я пишу команду в боте, он пишет неправильный баланс(изначально на балансе было 20000):

> Ваш баланс: 90000

Я не знаю откуда он берёт такое число да ещё и прибавляет, когда нужно было наоброт вычитать, прошу помочь мне! В сфере программирования я новичок

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хехе, занимательный случай. В файл и пишется 9000, но поскольку зачем-то применяются `r+` и `seek()`, то в файле ещё остаётся последний 0 от 20000, а '9000'+'0' как раз и получается '90000'.

Решение из комментария: после записи вызвать `file.truncate()`.

PS. *Удалил свой предыдущий совет, потому что он в некоторых местах приведет к другим проблемам.*

*Вообще, работу с файлами тут надо оптимизировать. Не нужно открывать/закрывать файл на каждый чих. Достаточно каждый файл открыть один раз и закрыть когда он больше не нужен. И используйте для работы с файлами конструкцию with open(), тогда файл будет закрыт автоматически.*

Comment: Не все, а только там где запись, там где чтение - `'r'`. Ну и еще close нужно нормально вызывать со скобками)

Comment: @insolor где только чтение, там вроде и так 'r', но я каждый случай не проверял, конечно.

Comment: А, ну еще можно режим открытия не менять, а просто после записи `file.truncate()` делать.

Comment: Ну, там после первого else идет открытие с r+, потом чтение, изменение и запись.

Comment: @insolor точно.

Comment: Да ну вообще лучше "атомарно" всё делать, в том числе чтение и запись файлов. А все эти `"r+"` режимы только запутывают )